# How to append a value from php inside my JS file?

Tags: php, javascript

Basically I want to read and write to a file then save all the compiled content another file.

Steps:

1. Say I have a file *mycode.js* with this code:

   ```
     var url = '';     //this will be field throug form in php
   ```
2. Now in php, I will input a value of that url e.g `www.google.com`
3. How will I be able to append the url I just entered to my js file?
   Expected output:

   ```
   var url = 'www.google.com';
   ```
4. Also follow question, upon successful append of the value to my JS file I will now create a new file (*newlyappend.js*), like a save as thing. Where the content of the file is the newly append code:

   ```
   var url = 'www.google.com';
   ```

Would like to achieve this using php.

Comment: for what I got from your question, you are basically trying to modify mycode.js and then save the changed file as newlyappend.js?

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you're trying to do here. If you are simply trying to use a PHP variable in JS, you can do it like this: var someVar = '<?=$my_php_var?>';

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Comment: If you don't want to put PHP code in your Javascript source and `include` it (that would be the easiest way) but rather want to make a statis file on the server with this value then you could  `file_put_contents('newlyappend.js', preg_replace('/^\s*var\s+url\s*=\s*[\'"]{2}\s*;\s*$/m', "var url = '$urlFromPHP';", file_get_contents('mycode.js'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `.js` file content as a string:

```
$js = file_get_contents( '/path/to/file/mycode.js' );
```

`$js` will now hold the content of the file.

Replace the empty variable line with a value assignment:

```
$url = 'www.google.com';
$js = str_replace( "var url = '';", "var url = '$url';", $js );
```

Write the new content back to a new js file:

```
file_put_contents( '/path/to/file/newlyappend.js', $js );
```

Make sure you have proper permissions to read & write files from the specified paths.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your js file to mycode.php and write php code inside the file like this, so php engine will execute the file

```
var url = "<?php echo($YOUR-URL); ?>";
```

Now in your html file include this file just like you include js file in the script tag. Give src="mycode.php". Browser will treat it as a js file and you can access the varible url in your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just include PHP code inside the `<script></script>` section of your HTML templates / web pages because chances are, the file extension is `.php`:

```
<script>
    var jsVar = "<?php echo $phpVar ?>";
</script>
```

A solution for this is to make your server parse all files ending in `.js`. Just create a `.htaccess` if it doesn’t exist in the directory in which you wish to include and run PHP code inside all `.js` files. Add these lines at the end of .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js
```

Also you may use php5-script instead of x-httpd-php5 in some cases. And you may also try this with regular expressions to better match specific criteria:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Now you can add all the PHP code you can inside any JavaScript files with a .js extension, the server will automatically parse and run them when the client side requests the file. Hope this helps! :)